# How to extend an angle and find new two points

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle

I know the angle between points A, B, and C (solid lines). I want to extend the angle on both sides for certain degrees, e.g., 45 degrees. But I don't know the new points (points D and E with dotted lines in the attached figure). How can I find the new points? Any help in this regard is appreciated.

[Attached Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuFP2.jpg)

Comment: Are you talking about utilizing analytic geometry? Are the equations of the segments/lines given?

Comment: I mean the equations for the new points at a certain angle.

Comment: Start with equations of lines and than use the trigonometric tan function. The slope of the lines relate to the angle with x by the tan functions.